# sys.argv is different depending on the method of invocation of script

Tags: python-2.7, command-line-arguments

I have a simple Python script that all it does is:

```
import sys
print sys.argv
```

When I open `cmd` and type

```
MyScript.py arg1
```

I get:

```
['C:\\MyScript.py']
```

But when type:

```
python MyScript.py arg1
```

I get:

```
['C:\\MyScript.py', 'arg1']
```

I've looked around [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue7936) but did not find my answer.

I've uninstalled and re-installed `Python 2.7.9` and it did not resolve it. 
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually had the same problem, i had to iterate through all python's occurrences over the registry and manually append the %* to the execution path

```
c:\...python "%1" to c:\...python "%1" %*
```